# Best way to implement CI with Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

We have a setup of local development sites built with Drupal 8 and we want to have a way to synchronize the data between them. Some of the developers are not very familiar with the CMS and they're working on the front-end part, so we don't want to make them move data by hand. We're looking for the best way to automatically sync the content and configuration between our instances. So far for the file system we're using git, but for the database we haven't found a suitable solution. What do you suggest we should do here ? We are also going to use a similar if not the same setup when we move our site to staging and production environments. We have Jenkins setup with some books for the git, so it is possible to run bash command as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this might bring up quite some different opinions. As there is no "best way". It always depends on your setup, your specific requirements and you :)

That said, I love to CI D8 with [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/). I already published a simple sample repo that may help you to kick-start your own setup.

https://github.com/leymannx/drupal-circleci-behat

You push to a branch. CircleCI will build the site in a docker container, run tests and when all tests are green it will start deployment by SSHing into the live or dev server and fire a deployment script (`git pull`, `composer install`, `drush updb`, ...).

And I tend to always use the following Composer template for Drupal 8 projects. As it provides a good eco system for stuff like this:

https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project